# Is there a way to reuse code if my objects have different hierarchy?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, dozer

My problem is that I am dealing with 2 different jaxb generated object hierarchies. The objects have the same name and 99.9% the same structure but they are in different packages:

```
 xy.z.fpml.transparency.IdentifiedCurrency
 xy.z.fpml.recordkeeping.IdentifiedCurrency
```

As you might imagine I can't modify the objects and they have nothing in common that I can link to, no superclass or interface, etc

IntelliJ says it is duplicate code but I have my hands tied. Is there any way to do kind of a generic method that will accept both kind of objects ? Maybe some reflection ? ( I am asumming I can't ...)

Comment: If you can give JAXB a custom schema, you can create a third schema with the common parts, and recast the other two schemas to include the third one. This should force the generated code for each of the first two schemas to include a reference to an object of the common composed type.

Comment: Wait, this is generated code. Why do you care? Is it just because intellij is telling you to care?

Comment: I work on a legacy app. I found my self having 2 separate packages with 99% the same code(transparency and recordkeeping). Each package uses one of the hierarchy of objects generated by jaxb. At first I said OK, I will just extract in a superclass. Then I so that I can't, the classes used as arguments come from jaxb, have the same name but are in different packages and I have about 10 classes that are 'duplicated' and have to be mantained ...so I want to unite them if I can

Answer (score 1):

If the classes come from jaxb then you probably need to maintain their source, some XSD or Schema document, and not the generated classes itself.

If the problem is only with the IDE warnings then add exception for this case and forget about them.

Comment: For example I have a class with this method :                                                                           
     `private IdentifiedCurrency getIdentifiedCurrency(String value) {
        IdentifiedCurrency ccy= new IdentifiedCurrency();
        ccy.setCurrencyScheme(HTTP_SCHEME);
        identifiedCurrency.setValue(value);
        return ccy;
    }`                                                                                                       But I have the same method in another class using the identifiedCurrency from the other hierarchy.5k lines are in this state

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to avoid code duplication is to use Dozer or BeanUtils to make a deepCopy of the object.

```
 private xy.z.fpml.transparency.IdentifiedCurrency getIdentifiedCurrency(String value) {
    xy.z.fpml.transparency.IdentifiedCurrency identifiedCurrency = new IdentifiedCurrency();
    identifiedCurrency.setCurrencyScheme(SCHEMA);
    identifiedCurrency.setValue(value);
    return identifiedCurrency;
}

 private xy.z.fpml.recordkeeping.IdentifiedCurrency getIdentifiedCurrency(String value) {
    xy.z.fpml.transparency.IdentifiedCurrency currency = getIdentifiedCurrency(value);
    xy.z.fpml.recordkeeping.IdentifiedCurrencycurrency copy = new ...();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(currency , copy );  
    return identifiedCurrency;
}
```

For the second hierarchy I will just have another method calling the first one and copying the results. What I added is just a simple example, it may seem overhead since we have the same number of lines, but there are methods duplicated with 50-100 lines and in total there is an entire hierarchy duplicated.

Do you think there is a better approach to this ?